# Android keyboard not showing when EditText is in focus, inside Alert Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

Lots of people seem to have had this problem, but none of their solutions are helping me.

Basically I create a custom alert dialog, and set a linearlayout as it's view.

If I add an editText to it before showing the dialog, everything works fine and the keyboard show up.

However, if I add editText to the linear layout while the dialog is up, the keyboard doesn't show up even if I click on the edit text and even if it didn't have focus previously.

I tried

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

however no keyboard shows up ever.

I also tried:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(imm!=null)
{
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

from inside the alertdialog, however the keyboard that shows up, is behind the dialog and is therefore unusable.

I just don't understand what the problem is, do any of you know a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically having an alert dialog was my problem. It didn't let me set content view properly and using setView(view) was my downfall.

By extending my custome dialog class to a dialog instead of an alert dialog and using setContentView() instead of setView()(as available in the alert dialog), I no longer have issues with the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that since the place where you enter text is hidden initially (or nested or something), AlertDialog is automatically setting the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM` or `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` so that things don't trigger a soft input to show up.

The way to fix it is the following:

```
(...)
// Create the dialog and show it
Dialog dialog = builder.create()
dialog.show();

// After show, clear the flags and set the soft input mode
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I have a DialogFragment which creates an AlertDialog in onCreateDialog(). Therefore there is no "diaolg.show()". I used setOnFocusChangeListener() of my TextInputEditText to clear the flags and make the keyboard visible.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before and solved by adding this to my dialog class

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    return dialog;

}
```

You said you used this code before but didn't mention where you used it. 
Try it and let me know

and to hide it after click close or finish use this code:

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Well my friend, your answer both was and wasn't a solution.

Basically I was able to solve the problem just now by switching from alert dialog to a basic dialog, which your answer led me to try. 
So have an upvote! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
 imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

If that does not work try this:

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
Runnable r=new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
               imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
}; 
handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
```

The second method will delay opening the keyboard 100 ms in case the view is still getting set up etc